# strcmp function not working properly

Tags: c, string, structure, strcmp

I have a **`delete` function on array of structures `books`**. I'm passing it an array of records, `author of book` and `name of book` and `size of the list`.

Now here **given that `list[0].author` and `list[5].author` and `author` all are equal to "Dan Brown" (same string)**

```
void delete(struct books *list,char author[],char name[],int n)
{
    int i,a;
    a=strcmp(list[0].author,list[5].author);
    printf("%d\n",a);              // prints 0
    a=strcmp(list[0].author,author);
    printf("%d\n",a);              // prints other than 0
}
```

Why is it happening? What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a `'\n'` at the end of some of the strings?

Comment: `list[0].author` gets input from `fgets()` function and `author` from `strcpy()`

Comment: Either use a debugger or `printf` all the 3 strings `printf("%s|%s|%s|\n", list[0].author, list[5].author, author);` should print `Dan Brown|Dan Brown|Dan Brown|`

Comment: Use `strsrt()` to find substring, or check `strlen()` to see if strings are really the same...  Check more than one thing sometimes is necessary to validate input before processing it.

Comment: @GiulioFranco it's not printing `Dan Brown|Dan Brown|Dan Brown|` but printing `Dan Brown` in 3 different lines. I think `fgets()` leaves a stray `\n` at the end(?)

Comment: @xmpirate Check the length of each string using `strlen`

Comment: @ryyker, Do you mean `strchr()` instead od `strstr()`? (`\n` is a `char`)

Comment: @Kunal yeah the lengths are different.

Comment: @xmpirate This means you have stray characters. Prune them.

Comment: @xmpirate I updated my answer with a couple of ways to get around the `'\n'` issue

Comment: @AlterMann - no, `strstr()`.  I am suggesting that using two methods to verify the input of each string (i.e. `strlen()` & `strstr()`) would be one way to address the issue OP is having.  Actually, when dealing with strings, assumptions are often dangeous, and double checking is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`fgets`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/):

> Reading stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or error. **The newline, if any, is retained.**

This means that `fgets` will **not** remove the final `'\n'` from the end of the read string. Thus, your strings are:

1. "Dan Brown"
2. "Dan Brown"
3. "Dan Brown\n"

They're **not** equal.

This is a very common issue when using `fgets`. That's why I usually prefer `scanf`, like this:

```
char buffer[BUF_LEN];
char format[16];
int scanf_result;

sprintf(format, "%%%u[^\n]", BUF_LEN);
//....
do
{
  //TODO: Ask for input
  scanf_result = scanf(format, buffer);
  switch (scanf_result)
  {
    case -1: //TODO: Print error message and exit
    case 0: //TODO: Print error mesage and break
  }
  //Discard remainings of buffered input line
  while (getchar() != '\n') {;}
} while (1); //Ugly, but plain
```

Otherwise, you can use `fgets` with something like this:

```
int buf_len;

//TODO: Ask for input
while (fgets(buffer, BUF_LEN, stdin) == NULL)
{
  //TODO: Check and handle error
}
buf_len = strlen(buffer);
//Remove trailing '\n', if present
if (buffer[buf_len - 1] == '\n')
{
  buffer[--buf_len] = '\0';
}
```

Even though it's easier, I don't like this second method, because `strlen` scans the string another time to determine its length. In most cases, this is not a performance issue, I avoid it because I have my own mental issues.

Comment: How can I remove the stray `\n`?

Comment: @xmpirate `str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0'`

Comment: @Giulio Franco: +1, according to documentation as you have mentioned,the newline, if any, is retained. Do `buffer[--buf_len] = '\0';` without a check if this one is really a `\n` isn't dangerous? I mean, it may not be the new line. I've always check it

Comment: @TheMask yes, you're right. It's dangerous. As I wrote, I never really use that.

Comment: strlen() can return zero: `if (buffer[buf_len - 1] == '\n')` -->>`if (buff_len && buffer[buf_len - 1] == '\n')` Less imporatant:  buff_len should be a size_t, not an int.

Comment: @wildplasser strlen **won't** return zero, because I know the buffer is large enough to hold 1 char and the trailing `'\0'`, and `fgets` gets a line. So, if `fgets` succeeds, then buffer will contain at least "\n", and so buf_len will be at least 1. As for the `size_t`, when I faced these issue against C, i barely knew `int` and `char`. I tried to keep it easy, since 4 instructions to read a line may be traumatic.

Comment: @GiulioFranco: Try reading a binary file, with NUL characters in it (for testing purposes you can use /dev/zero) fgets will stop at the first NUL byte, and strlen() will report zero length if that byte happens to be the first in the line. And the buffer size is irrelevant here. BTW what is `while (fgets(buffer, BUF_LEN, stdin) == NULL)` supposed to do , wait untill the EOF disappears?

Comment: @wildplasser From `man fgets` "fgets() and gets() functions do not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.". That's exactly what you're supposed to do in that while. Determine what happened, if it's something recoverable, go to the next iteration, otherwise return an error.

Comment: And fgets won't work properly if the file contains nul bytes (scanf won't either), regardless of what you do, because there is no way to know how much fgets actually read.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify your inputs.  Sometimes by more than one method is necessary.  Here, I am using `strlen()`, and `strstr()`, because if the length is `==`, and a *substring* exists, then the strings *ARE* equal.  So, try something like this to verify the input strings are what you thing they are before making a conclusion:

***Note:*** the enum is of course not necessary, but included here to add clarity to example of output.

```
enum    {
    SAME,     //0
    NOT_SAME  //1
}

void delete(struct books *list,char author[],char name[],int n)
{
    int i,a, len1, len2;
    A = NOT_SAME;
    len1 = strlen(list[0].author);
    len2 = (list[5].author);
    if(strstr(list[0].author,list[5].author) && (len1==len2)) a = SAME;
    printf("%d\n",a);              


    a = NOT_SAME;
    len1 = strlen(list[0].author);
    len2 = (author);
    if(strstr(list[0].author,author) && (len1==len2)) a = SAME;
    printf("%d\n",a);              

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check second strings by printing character by character.

Especially `author` string.

```
for(i=0; i < strlen(list[0].author);i++)
{
   if(list[0].author[i]!=author[i])
   {
     printf("this is position is not matching\n",i+1);
     //try to print characters and also print ascii characters.
     break; 
   }

}
//or simply try to use strncpy()
```

Comment: He is asking why `strcmp(list[0].author,author);` is not printing `0`.

Comment: @Kunal The obscure answer given here is that they are not equal, else that code would yield a result of 0.